# Mix two video together?

Tags: android, video, effect

I've certain effects by MP4 format , is it possiable to include them to sample video toghether (I mean mix 2 videos together) ? any way ? sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, ffmpeg can do this. have a look over here:

http://nerdcore-enthusiasm.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/crossfade-two-videos-clips-from-command_340.html

and here for the code;

http://mimoart.ooz.dk/crossfade.text